# CPU and RAM running randomly when no app is running?

Tags: security, centos, vps

Is it a normal thing to have random bursts of CPU usage going to 100% for a few seconds and RAM usage also keeps changing on its own even when my app is not running on my VPS server and no client is active either?
It does have a Apache http server running but I never use it.
My usage is for a Java application only but that also was not running during this time.
I have a domain name and an SSL certificate, not sure whether that is causing this?
I am worried that some hacker has put a malware in my VPS running on CentOS 7.
How am I supposed to check what is the reason for these bursts of computation.
These correspond with network I/O as well but that is in kiloBytes.

[image]

Comment: - did you check the system processes? Check if there are any system processes or background tasks running on your VPS that might be consuming CPU and RAM resources.

- did you check the access logs of the Apache server for any suspicious activity or attempts to access your server?

- did you configure any SSL/TLS Certificate?

- (probably I missed it...) Is it a Cloud Instance/VM or a physical one? If it is cloud which  CPS? SKU?

Comment: After using htop and atop I realised that primarily fail2ban-server was using a lot of CPU time. I guess I have to live with bots trying to hack my VPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `htop` or similar and it could show you what is using those cpu resources at the times when the spikes occur.

If you dont have htop you can install it with `sudo yum install htop` . However note that htop is only showing you what is happening at that time, i.e. a real time view.

However there is also `atop`. One of the main benefits of atop over tools like top and htop is its ability to log system and process information over time. This can be helpful for diagnosing issues that only occur intermittently or for a short period of time which sounds exactly like the thing you need for issues you are having.

You can install atop with `sudo yum install atop` .
You can start the atop process and logging with:

```
sudo systemctl start atop
sudo systemctl enable atop
```

To view system resources in real-time, you can just run `atop`. To view the logs, you can use `atop -r`, followed by the log file's path. By default, atop logs are stored in `/var/log/atop/` .

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Should I keep running htop or atop on my VPS 24x7 so that it can log these events? Or is it just a one time run when I want to check yesterday's data?

Comment: After using htop and atop I realised that primarily fail2ban-server was using a lot of CPU time. I guess I have to live with bots trying to hack my VPS?

Comment: You have already seen what the problem is but just in case :
you run atop (with those two commands in the answer) and then you check the logs later, say the next day with atop -r <logpath>